# Tomcat6 constant crashes

Tags: memory, ubuntu, memory-management, nginx, tomcat6

We had 5 applications over a linode(Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit) of 1G RAM. Recently we moved one of the applications out of that linode to another of 512M. The application is built on Java EE and was working pretty stable on the old server. On the new server however tomcat(Version 6 on both servers) crashes every now and then without any logs. The only difference on the new server is that we are using nginx as the web server against apache2 on the old and the new server uses Ubuntu 12, 64 bit. There is no reason to doubt a memory leak because the application was behaving well on the old server. Are there any tomcat optmizations to be done to prevent such kind of crashes. I doubt if the reason is load due to traffic(since the new server has lower RAM) as well, because even in the middle of the night when there are just about 10 concurrent users, tomcat still crashes. Any insight towards the problem would be appreciated.

I checked the RAM usage and tomcat constantly occupies about 60% of the memory and all of a sudden crashes and goes to 0. I have used a bash script and run it as a cron job every 5 minutes on the new server to check if tomcat is down and restart it automatically. Could that be causing the issue? The script is mentioned below

```
if [ "$(/etc/init.d/tomcat6 status)" == " * Tomcat servlet engine is not running." ]; then /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start; fi
```

Please note, I am not an expert at server configuration. I can just about configure a server to install and get required things running.

Comment: Are the JVMs identical ? Are their settings for xmx, permgen...the same ?

Comment: No... since the ram is lesser on the new server I have set the values to half tht is 128m and 256m against 256m and 512m on the old server.

Comment: Perhaps the linux OOM killer is killing your tomcat. You should check the syslogs for any unusual entrees at the time of crashes. Also look look at the jvm versions in both machines.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.04 on the old server and a Ubuntu 12 64bit OS on the new server. Will that consume more RAM?

Comment: Yes, 64bit JVMs have a somewhat higher memory overhead. Can you run  java -version  on both servers ?

Comment: The old server shows 
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing) while new server shows java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You moved your app from a 32-bit Hotspot JVM to a 64-bit Openjdk JVM. And on the new server you have less RAM.

First I would try to install the same 32bit Hotspot JVM on the new server,and see if the crashes still occur. If they do, I would start adding more memory, and adjust xmx etc' accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the RAM to 1GB, downgraded to Ubuntu 12, 32 Bit, reinstalled JVM 32 bit and now the server works like a charm. I was unable to zero down on the root cause, but the most possible cause should be either the 64bit OS or the 64 bit JVM eating too much memory. Thanks for your help.